# Ramda - filtering array of objects - curried fn parameters order

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, ramda.js

I want to implement filtering function generator in ramda.js. In my mind, it should works this way:

```
var a = filterFn(arrOfObjects)
var b = a(keyName)
var c = b(value)
```

It's very imporant to achieve this order of arguments, because the same array could be filtered using different conditions.

Currently I have the following code:

```
var g = R.curryN(2, R.compose(R.filter(R.__)(R.__), R.propEq))
g('classId')(2)(input)
```

but I want to have 'input' as first argument:

```
g(input)('classId')(1)
```

Here is a ramda REPL: [code](http://ramdajs.com/repl/?v=0.24.1#?var%20input%20%3D%20%5B%0A%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20%271%27%2C%20classId%3A%201%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20%272%27%2C%20classId%3A%201%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20%273%27%2C%20classId%3A%201%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20%274%27%2C%20classId%3A%202%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20%275%27%2C%20classId%3A%202%0A%20%20%7D%0A%5D%0A%0Avar%20g%20%3D%20R.curryN%282%2C%20R.compose%28R.filter%28R.__%29%28R.__%29%2C%20R.propEq%29%29%0Ag%28%27classId%27%29%282%29%28input%29%0A%0A%2F%2F%20i%20want%20to%20have%20input%20as%20first%20argument%3A%0A%2F%2F%20g%28input%29%28%27classId%27%29%281%29)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I would just use something like this:

```
R.curry((list, name, value) => R.filter(R.propEq(name, value), list));
```

Ramda does not include an arbitrary parameter-reordering mechanism, just [`flip`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#flip) and the [`__` placeholder](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#__).

Answer (score 0):

You don't really want this function to be pointfree :)

```
var g = R.compose(
  R.curryN(2, R.compose)(R.__, R.propEq),
  R.curryN(2, R.compose),
  R.flip(R.filter)
)
```

Or atleast make sure future maintainer would never know where you live :)

How to get something terrible like this one.

First, you write pointful version of your function which is straight forward.

```
list => prop => value => R.filter(R.propEq(prop)(value))(list)
```

or

```
list => prop => value = R.flip(R.filter)(list)(R.propEq(prop)(value))
```

Then go to [Pointfree.io](http://pointfree.io/) and use some haskell syntax `\x y z -> f x (g y z)`. Where `f` if `flip filter` and `g` is `propEq`

Tool would produce `(. g) . (.) . f`

Then you convert this back to javascript to make future maintainer cry. [Demo](http://ramdajs.com/repl/?v=0.24.1#?var%20input%20%3D%20%5B%0A%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20%271%27%2C%20classId%3A%201%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20%272%27%2C%20classId%3A%201%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20%273%27%2C%20classId%3A%201%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20%274%27%2C%20classId%3A%202%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20%275%27%2C%20classId%3A%202%0A%20%20%7D%0A%5D%0A%0A%2F%2F%28.%20g%29%20.%20%28.%29%20.%20f%0A%0Avar%20g%20%3D%20R.compose%28%0A%20%20R.curryN%282%2C%20R.compose%29%28R.__%2C%20R.propEq%29%2C%0A%20%20R.curryN%282%2C%20R.compose%29%2C%0A%20%20R.flip%28R.filter%29%0A%29%0A%20%20%0A%0A%0Ag%28input%29%28%27classId%27%29%282%29).